# Editable Webview/TextView ? Or Any other Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uitextview

I am working on a project which can edit any document file whether it is doc, rtf, txt, pdf file.

After editing user can save or you can say update that file.

Please advise .. how can anyone edit pdf or doc and re save it  ?

Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly don't mean "any document".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for editing pdf or doc files in iOS4. If you want this you'll have to write it yourself.

A UIWebView can natively interpret a lot of document formats but there is no editing for this. If you just want to open these formats I would recommend a UIWebView. If you really need to save to a certain format, you'll have to look around for a framework that can save text to the formats you need. Or you're going to have to do it yourself.